# Reimplementing SwiftUI's `frame` modifier using the `Layout` protocol

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to reimplement the `frame(width:height:alignment:)` modifier, or rather, a simplified version that takes non-optional values. The goal is for the following code to produce the exact same result as if I had written `frame` instead of `myFrame`, for any alignment I pass it (including custom alignments):

```swift
Rectangle()
    .fill(.red)
    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    .myFrame(width: 250, height: 250, alignment: .bottomTrailing)
    .border(.blue)
```

Here's my attempt so far:

```swift
extension View {
    func myFrame(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, alignment: Alignment) -> some View {
        MyFrame(size: CGSize(width: width, height: height), alignment: alignment) {
            // make sure we only pass in a single view
            VStack { self }
        }
    }
}

private struct MyFrame: Layout {
    let size: CGSize
    let alignment: Alignment
    
    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
        size
    }
    
    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
        let dimensions = subviews[0].dimensions(in: ProposedViewSize(size))
        let pointInSubview = CGPoint(
            x: dimensions[alignment.horizontal],
            y: dimensions[alignment.vertical]
        )
        let position = /* somehow use `pointInSubview` to figure out where to place the subview */
        subviews[0].place(at: position, proposal: ProposedViewSize(size))
    }
}
```

Figuring out where to align the subview in the subview's local coordinate system is quite easy, the problem is figuring out which location in the given `CGRect` bounds to align it with. Can this be done, or is the `Layout` protocol incapable of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want the subview to be placed at the equivalent point in the larger frame, which means you can derive a unit point from the alignment guide and size, and then use that unit point with the larger bounds to drive positioning, like this:

```swift
func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
    for subview in subviews {
        let dimensions = subview.dimensions(in: ProposedViewSize(size))
        let pointInSubview = CGPoint(x: dimensions[alignment.horizontal], y: dimensions[alignment.vertical])
        var anchorX: CGFloat = 0
        var anchorY: CGFloat = 0
        if pointInSubview.x != 0 {
            anchorX = pointInSubview.x / dimensions.width
        }
        if pointInSubview.y != 0 {
            anchorY = pointInSubview.y / dimensions.height
        }

        let positionX = bounds.origin.x + (bounds.width * anchorX)
        let positionY = bounds.origin.y + (bounds.height * anchorY)
        subview.place(
            at: CGPoint(x: positionX, y: positionY),
            anchor: UnitPoint(x: anchorX, y: anchorY),
            proposal: proposal)
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work for custom alignments, I should have emphasized better that those need to work, too. It's the only missing piece from being able to reimplement the `frame` modifiers entirely.

Comment: FWIW I wrapped self in a VStack in order to make sure subviews has exactly one element, regardless of what kind of view .myFrame is called on. I'm using `_UnaryViewAdaptor(self)` in my actual code, but to the best of my knowledge any of the standard stacks do the job equally well.

Comment: Ah ok I wasn't sure if you were looking at this as an intellectual exercise or had a specific purpose in mind

Comment: @TimVermeulen I have reworked my answer to (hopefully) take custom alignments into account. I'm still not really clear on your use case for this (e.g. what specific layout are you trying to achieve?) but this seems to match your requirements better

Comment: I really like how elegant this is compared to your initial answer, and I think it works well for all alignments that can be expressed as a ratio of the width/height of the view! Not all alignments can necessarily be expressed as a `UnitPoint` though, since they're able to apply an absolute offset as well. So this doesn't quite pass the "works exactly like `.frame` for all custom alignments" test, but is a good answer nonetheless. (Note: you pass `proposal` to `subview.place`, which I think needs to be `ProposedViewSize(size)`.)